# iOS - how can we offer discount through promo code for in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to understand: how do promo code work? And also will the Apple store take care of reducing the price of the in-app purchase after the user has applied for the promo code from app store?

Answer (score 20):

Apple has offered promo codes for in-app purchases [since October 28, 2016](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10282016a).

There are some limitations (only 100 for each version).

Here’s a step by step guide on how to generate these promo codes for your Apple app:

1. Log in to iTunes Connect.
2. Click the My Apps icon.
3. Select the app you wish to generate promo codes for.
4. Select the Features Tab.
5. Click Promo Codes, listed in the left-hand menu at the bottom.
6. Enter the number of codes you’re after. You’re only given 100 for each version of app, and they expire after 4 weeks…so choose wisely!
7. Click Generate Code(s) once you’ve entered the number and agree to the contract you’re prompted with!
8. The codes will be listed on the screen and will also be sent to the account team agent via their contact email.

[image]

**Redeeming the codes.**

Here’s some instructions you can send to the people you’re giving the codes to.

**On iPhone / iPad**

Open the App Store
Tap Featured and scroll to the bottom
Tap Redeem and enter your credentials
Enter the code

**On iTunes**

1. Open the iTunes Store
2. Click Redeem and enter your credentials
3. Enter the code
4. The app will start downloading if it's redeeming an app promo code.
5. For in-app purchase promo codes, the app will automatically download if the app is free and not currently installed on the device.
6. If the app is paid, you will need to download the app in order to redeem the in-app purchase.

NB: Turn on automatic downloads if you want the app downloaded to your devices automatically. On the device go to Settings, iTunes and App Store, and ensure Automatic Downloads for apps is turned on.

Alternatively, sync your device with iTunes after the app has downloaded

References:

1. https://getauthentic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000958634-Generating-promo-codes-for-your-iOS-app
2. https://support.crookneckapps.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000054666-Redeeming-in-app-purchase-promo-codes
3. https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev50869de4a
4. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/230792/194578

Answer (score 6):

First thing Apple is not providing anything like promo code. Second thing you cannot reduce price of in-app purchase from the code.

Even though you want to implement this feature, then it can done by creating two in-app purchases. One is original price and other is at discounted price.

**Let's understand by taking this example.**

```
in-app purchase 1 - $2.99

in-app purchase 2 - $0.99
```

When promo code not implemented then in-app purchase 1 will take place otherwise in-app purchase 2 will take place.

All this thing you have to manage from the code.

Comment: Please refer this https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev50869de4a

Comment: These promo codes is used for testing purpose or if you want to give free access to some user.

Comment: Ya got it and these promo codes are used to offer free downloads of the app itself and not for In app purchases right ?

Comment: No, it give free access to in-app purchase also but you cannot reduce price by using this promo codes.

Comment: @Indrajeet: I got the idea about the discounted subscription as you mention in answer. We need to create a separate subscription. But my question is while canceling a subscription or on the subscription page on iphone. User can goto app subscription from setting where her get option to cancel subscription or see list of avaliable subscription and can choose from other in list. I don't want to show discounted subscription in that list. I want just actual one which had original price.  How can I remove that discounted sibscription from cancel subscription page.

Comment: @BhaveshJariwala In your case, check for an active subscription if any subscription is active hide the discounted subscriptions and if the subscription is inactive then show all subscriptions to the user.

Comment: @Indrajeet: I mean to say here is: It not showing subscription inside app. It is about apple showing subscription list form it' setting. I don't think so we may control that. What your thought. Here is link which will help your to my case: https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202039
on this link 4th screenshot in that you can see it is listing subscriptions. I don't want to show discounted subscription in that.

Comment: @BhaveshJariwala oh ok, I got your problem, do you using promo code for giving a discount to the user? If yes then, it is difficult to hide discounted subscription.

Comment: @Indrajeet: I am using promo code(not the provided by apple. it is custom implementation in my system for mocking up discounted subscription) in my system. Based on applied code I am showing them a subscription. Any hack or work around that.

Comment: Can we apply free custom promocodes in application?

Comment: Yes, you can apply by creating multiple In-App purchase, as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the Settings > Purchases/Subscriptions it would only show what you are paying for or what is getting deducted every month/quarter/year. There’s no option to show the non-discounted price.

Answer (score 0):

### How do Promo Codes work?

Promo codes allow potential customers or reviewers to get free copies of apps or in-app purchases on iOS, macOS, or tvOS. Each code can be used once, and they're valid for four weeks. In-app purchase promo codes automatically download the app if it's not already installed, and if the app is for sale, the customer must purchase it. **Up to 100** promo codes can be provided **per in-app purchase product**, with a limit of **1,000 total codes** **every six months**. Promo codes are for **non-commercial use only** and **expire after 28 days**.

For more information, see [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/offer-promo-codes/request-and-manage-promo-codes/).

### To generate and manage Promo Codes (Up-to-date in 2023)

1. Log in to AppStore Connect
2. Select "My Apps", then your app
3. Go to "Services" tab
4. Select "Promo Codes" from the left panel